# Cast String to Double using Postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql, casting, double

How can I cast a string containing double value to numeric value, keeping precision. If the string is not a double, then convert to zero

Comment: What makes a string a double?  Is "1" a double?  How about "1.0"?

Comment: Both "1" and "1.0" are doubles

Comment: I edited my answer to return double also if the input is a string containing a integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query uses a regex match to return a double if the input string has "numeric content", also only digits or decimal numbers with a point as separator like `1.0`, `18789.903`. Returns 0 if the input string contains non numerics characters like `10hghj`. The minus character in front of the string is allowed (negative double):

```
-- returns 1.2143
WITH subquery AS (SELECT '1.2143'::text as value) 
   SELECT 
   CASE WHEN value ~ '^(-)?[0-9]+\.?([0-9]+)?$'
        THEN value::double precision 
        ELSE 0 
   END FROM subquery;

-- returns 0 because input is a contains not digits characters 
-- (the regex expression is the same) 
WITH subquery AS (SELECT '1214gh'::text as value) 
   SELECT 
   CASE WHEN value ~ '^(-)?[0-9]+\.?([0-9]+)?$'
        THEN value::double precision 
        ELSE 0 
   END FROM subquery;
```

Explanation:

The `~` is the regex match operator in PostgreSql. More info here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-TABLE

The `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE` expression allows you to change returned value depending on one or more conditions. In the WHEN part are all statements allowed which return a boolean value. More info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-conditional.html

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. Now it works with a single digit too